# React Js - Typescript 4.2.3 JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have created some Typescript Types to help me during the development of React App. If I use them separately, they work well, they are fast and not using any additional memory, as expected. The problem starts when I try to use them together with other types and on my reactjs app it shows `JavaScript heap out of memory`.

I have created this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-dev.20210401#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbwL4CgD0AqDK7d3AZQgFtg4ALYAGzGCjgBUBPWgZzgEMA7AEzgEkuMOgDMOAY2CsAdNJx4MaFClCRYcGCzIBhbgCFgAUXDcewHgB4GcUMN7sIAIwBWwcfAC8cJ6-cAaOAAROC9WGCgASy4AcwA%20EMQcOGSANw4qAFdgAC5GJOSzMQyqGFzAlFQUKOEoMUk4PQ5WMgRlSurRCTIAVWb6W2B7BqaW-LgInlywyJi-MagIKhy4XS4DYzBTcwsAJUXgWLnk5K4IYSnwqOi59qFO%20r2lmxA7HnZG5sTj8cm4aaujscMn1cqt1iZeNtenRDmMQBcZtEKso0GhGOQIuwOrUunAAO4RKhUOCOMiqLZ8KJwcQRKDiYoceh4jhMOTYupkAAaz1e7xGX2OEwRALGXA4pGFszGwLooP0RghZks0KgsO%20CyWcrWCs2kMsjwO832rC14N1St2%20wA2gBdWLIlCaWhwABSECiFgA0gEAArxLyenmDN5-S4xOAAHzgXAyxFJ9AA-GMfUGhv9w1GY3G6HAk99vgADAAkCE9SBLACIK6mQymE3Aq3BchXpBXywgfUgC2NvrkuMAUjm%20wO6ABuZROsg%20qDAEQREAAdQiMHIFh9AQIAW0CQA5NId-64CmBkMdzvc3Biwh09E4AAyQhdpuXks3%209H9tvh-aT9h28PgguwnLRCDAKhlyXFcAEEiR9CBWFYCJHCWbQSEcKIOBgCIIC4VgLAIGt2BvAJghPEMb39MY3zI9gCPrN9sh7Y4CJouAzwvdjGPzbjCEIl8ECiEQcwYdtAnbQSc26J88x42TrCjN0PQYDcwIg5dyBgqg4IQpCULQjCsJwvDuhI2J7Vk2TcgIccUSweR0UxOARAyLh3Gwrh8UJYkZxgDIoA89JiUgHT0KeABrYAmHYFdMOpbgSTJRVzG8DzlJSqgmA0CANEoOAADk4DMYAwDgJZByoeQlEnOBPUi1gwR1CkAH0rACArWKzeMSOKlc%20M6uhbUPdqXmDdhAh68grR3JYYhXHcbQvftB3oLjjmsViGo2ClcyY5Jaqizakp4FqGCmtJMmAea2u6sAV3iVbuPWkahigqAoBZCwJPobp4nrfb6vlLa9Rakz8puu6m2UCy1r4nw3HgGToe%20VokYsq1AypCKmAgERGDgBaHtR-NTs9BbWLh9wdqJpHA1Yt9M1jeNdupnj6yvMsC0jV13S4Cx2a7AJ-sO81zBO9GbWuuArQARgCWRpHG27yDtcyWdR4dluZtWNboKGWaQK0sZxxgbS1njCdRpbdZUcBoHgaqhcBo7WvyvrGZzLwABZD0d7UgaVE7JcG2yFDgf24CxhwPILAB5TnHBGPgcMvf7Oc2d7SBqORcCqkD-aalqY8FurfT44jXY6936HB8g%20JcsLTjxLhbTgSjvmG3kggmqaZuiOaFsR-MY744XtsH2SY6mwoOGKGB5sh1Hh4t45h42p2Rb4ceePzwurWPZ6Q3%20jjzqyc9ch3afZ6umqS6PSXFYh5fuNXg-2Fe96mE%20rghO%2036ze4neFhQb-V9PfCasRbT-3zLkF%20ncKYIygcjRBPF0bjA8kbXGMcbQAFoEy5EAZPUmxcoq%20hnHORc6k1yC0OGDKWss4DywfsrVW1NUDazgDHZQwFnQEFUjAKC2gvSHl4eBGAkENKwXgohZCwBUJxgMu5PCtNX6hkRBeQM58dwBD3AePiX0arZT%20tlTRjo86KkDjVNqbtsz0C9oeQBaURHLgEUI7RWjaHB2qppf6LsO6jWjFXBI3sEi%20zNBSXx8RWL6J2BeGJOsoBcPQHZfA-Bcb8G8LQDyK4yCQDABkMAAQAAUkBqhXE8r1bJcBiAQBlClHKZB-YAEoAiVPECQMAhIcysHIBAPE0VcrVX9gEckepODsFUPDcw2dQ78DnuwMQYROC8HGPAHgEApBcB3PAWpHAeA8GXO5dIVTgDVKgEweQlUbZqHtmY80VhYYuHhoLPi3i6oRISFbKAVjK42KCfY8xLtvT5XtEk0ODBKCfBgHibKzlXKGVwviaAYUxnUnIIyYgAR0isGytkzKjIyCsHyZ0RZpgUUTPcMlXFhUcJbLgDsvZBycJHIALInOgOcnOKAljwCYNLfBioLCcntNyuATAABM-K7mcm0TKKA0gNTAGkLK%20V%20wDxcMwAoey8towjlgJQJYCF8SUA8uk-slLsq1MqeHKkZxKD0GYGwTF-SyAiEWFQXpZTQDijAlIFpuVcn5L%20D0vEDZ3W7KuPLaspKCQrhqfAbpvSlmZUEtAYgmF3JLJ4PZSprLTmZQABLAA4CVaICw%20lZTgNLaQYroiODgIUqkxBMriBGI0mwy1MpYVINqgAmjUuKHlmhkGXBkwYZTKnaHIAsUgXcUgMAgIsdgpLxCUHEMiyppA82MA4I4aZ9ksAHuSRgAQOUojroxFidgLbgRlIrAAMSggwKCAAZMOOwdgxx2LkQQs4hJuUHFUxkYVsFtOIJsdw7B%20yMgoEWkq4FiAjs0hAFt8KnIcE6XwbBroOBpAIOISIt0YPFu8BkeAxtN3sorPZZOTa4BgAWL4VZflx25QLEwRkg6YCMhgAWaZuBD1HsuaY500IACKWQzkx1uoo%205rEPjAGeaxV5UUXbBP%20XctKnoQXVTExJpgUn4WsDFfc55rcEj50BfaHTzRxN0H09JoyABmEzNVkjqdMBYrTejv45mHvWJeOrNbCYaYqHYUhZ6tS814CzmnIkqP0X5jhz5PnBbgLpuzBnFGexc4GMz0XQvhZKJFkFoL7KOFIyi7GGQB1-GAGQO1Cn6nPF1IhZOxtBA1A5HAbky4dxESwkSRFUAwoRouSk3GHBjlbscmELyFAIjRHIAEEdabMpmr4NimdzQ2lDBgNlBNIaA1gD3ZykVpQ0s2b05loygrtEKqVX0FVSw1VAA), with a simple example, to explain the problem.

On the playground, pay attention to these types:

```js
// from line line #129 
type UseQueryOptions<T extends Base, K extends AllKeys<T, 4> > = Expand<T, K> 

type UseQueryOptions2<T , K  > = Expand_<T, K>  // line #129
type UseQueryOptions3<T , K  > = Expand_<T, K> extends infer O ? O : never  

type ExpandResult<T,K> = Expand_<T, K> extends infer O ? O : never
type UseQueryOptions4<T , K  > = ExpandResult<T,K>
```

As you can see, I tried multiple solutions to use `Expand_` with another Type.

Then, if you try to examine what is `Expand_<T, K>` (on line #129) (I mean, on the playground, move the mouse over Expand_<T, K>), the popup will be showed and you will see the function that runs this type. The memory used by the worker of typescript on Chrome, by this action, is stable (20/22 MB) and the info, on the popup, is showed correctly and fast as expected.

But, if you examine any of `UseQueryOptions[N]` (line #129/#131/#132/#135 ), the memory will start growing to 1.5GB (then, I think, Chrome cuts out the worker) and the popup will not show any information.

To be clear, here below you will find an image of what I mean regarding memory consumption:

In a normal situation the worker of typescript uses less than 30Mb, if you try to examine the type `Expand` on line #108 or `let y1` on lines #113/#114:

[image: Memory in normal situation]

But this is a memory that is used by the worker when I try to examine the `UseQueryOptions` types on lines #129/#131/#132/#135:

[image: Memory when I try to examine types]

All these explanations start because I'm also facing this anomaly with my reactjs app.

When I try to run `react start`, after adding similar Types that I mentioned before, the console gets blocked on `Files successfully emitted, waiting for typecheck results...` and the process `node` that run `react start` grows until reaching the limit of memory set on the node (can be 2Gb or 8 Gb, but is only a matter of time before it shows the error), and then showing:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[16365:0x1046ca000]   448881 ms: Mark-sweep 2028.9 (2059.0) -> 2020.9 (2059.3) MB, 766.2 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.132, current mu = 0.008) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[16365:0x1046ca000]   449641 ms: Mark-sweep 2028.9 (2059.3) -> 2020.9 (2059.3) MB, 754.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.073, current mu = 0.007) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x1012e4da5 node::Abort() (.cold.1) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
 2: 0x1000a6239 node::Abort() [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
 3: 0x1000a639f node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
 4: 0x1001e9007 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
 5: 0x1001e8fa3 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
 6: 0x100397e95 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
 7: 0x10039995a v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
 8: 0x100395029 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
 9: 0x1003928c1 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
10: 0x1003a115a v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
11: 0x1003a11e1 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
12: 0x10036eb87 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
13: 0x1006ed8d8 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
14: 0x100a7a239 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/Users/jure.prah/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/bin/node]
```

If I remove those lines from my project, then it runs as expected and without any error and the memory of the node is around 200 MB.

I hope this is enough and you have all the information in order to solve my problem.

Otherwise, I will be here to provide you with further information.

Comment: That doesn't look like a simple example to me. Perhaps if you build up to that kind of complexity from a barebones implementation, you will discover what specific feature you're adopting that causes the explosion.

Comment: Thanks @cefn for your comment. I write here because I'm not able to find what is this "specific feature" that I'm adopting. I think there is some knowledge that I'm missing regarding the Typescript recursion and Types/Interface/Generics. Could you please help out me with this difficulty?

Comment: I'd love to be able to help, but there's too much happening at once to be able to isolate the problem, which is why there is always such strong guidance to create a minimal repro... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Personally I find that 9 times out of 10 when I try to recreate the problem I make a discovery of what was wrong in the first place, then StackOverflow isn't needed.

Comment: Has similar problem, but with 4.3. 4.2 is ok in my project. still can't fix it. All I can do is lock ts version in 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

I haven't looked deeply at your set up or if your local memory usage is unusually high, but with that many dependencies it is definitely possible that you're just running out of memory. When I run my React applications locally I increase the amount of memory available to the Node process:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_OPTIONS='--max-old-space-size=8192' yarn start"
}
```

And with this have experienced a lot less crashes due to `JavaScript heap out of memory`.

Comment: You're missing the first `"` before the scripts object btw

Comment: Thanks! Fixed. @LoganDevine

Comment: @LoganDevine Thanks a lot for your feedback. I have already tried your solution before but the memory grows in any case up to the limit. Therefore, I have rewritten my question so you can understand better what I mean. I will appreciate it if you could look over it again.